# Need sum of a fact row grouped by start year and every year after it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- `customers` table, with columns `customer_id`, `created_at`
- `orders` table, with columns `order_id`, `customer_id`, `paid_at`, `amount`

I have to write a SQL query that breaks up the customers based on the year that they signed up (their cohort year), and determines total annual revenue for each cohort over the years (e.g., the 2011 cohort has total revenue of $x in year 1, $y in year 2, etc.)

```
select c.customer_id, c.created_at, SUM(o.amount) as Tot_amt
from customers c inner join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
group by c.created_at, Tot_amt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP BY year ( date column )

```
select   c.customer_id, YEAR(c.created_at), SUM(o.amount) as Tot_amt
from     customers c inner join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
group by c.customer_id, YEAR(c.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a break up of customers, the `customer_id` is meaningless in the final output, and only cohort years maters.

```
select YEAR(c.created_at), SUM(o.amount) as Tot_amt
from customers c inner join orders o using(customer_id)
group by YEAR(c.created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

To support your statement

> 2011 cohort has total revenue of $x in year 1, $y in year 2

you should have orderDate in your orders table

```
select 
  YEAR(c.created_at) as cohortYear, 
(YEAR(orderDate)-YEAR(c.created_at)+1) as YearNum,
SUM(o.amount) OVER( PARTITION by YEAR(c.created_at),(YEAR(orderDate)-YEAR(c.created_at)) ORDER BY YEAR(c.created_at),(YEAR(orderDate)-YEAR(c.created_at))) as Tot_amt
from customers c inner join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
```

In case you need a solution using group by

```
select 
  YEAR(c.created_at) as cohortYear, 
(YEAR(orderDate)-YEAR(c.created_at)+1) as YearNum,
SUM(o.amount) as Tot_amt
from customers c inner join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
group by YEAR(c.created_at),(YEAR(orderDate)-YEAR(c.created_at)+1)
order by YEAR(c.created_at),(YEAR(orderDate)-YEAR(c.created_at))
```